# 2020 macbook air ethernet disconnection problem

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, ethernet

I have been struggling with an ethernet disconnection problem on my Intel MacBook Air 2020 for several months now. The ethernet connection (through a wired USB-C lan connection) turns off after I have the camera on during a video conference for around 10 minutes. Turning to wifi works fine though. It happens with a variety of videoconferencing applications as skype, webex, zoom, GotoMeeting but strangely not with FaceTime. I thought it was an adaptor problem but I have changed four adaptors: [Satechi Multiport](https://satechi.net/products/type-c-multi-port-adapter-with-ethernet-v2?variant=45020091145) (tried 3 different ones) and [Belkin USB-C multimedia hub](https://www.belkin.com/us/p/P-F4U092/).

After updating to Big Sur the problem got even worse as it not only freezes my ethernet, but forces my home VDSL modem to disconnect from the Internet and I need to reboot it to get connected again.

I also posted it [at the Apple community forum](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/251991238?answerId=254018769022#254018769022) and it appears others have this problem as well. When I was returning the Satechi adaptors to the Apple dealer they were testing on their MacBooks before giving me a replacement and they were also experiencing the same issue.

Apple Support has given me a list of things to try like resetting SMC, NVRAM, PRAM, which I tried with no result. They also suggested to wipe my disk and do a clean installation of the OS which I have not tried yet as it will take me days of work to reinstall everything.

Does anyone have any idea of what the cause could be, or what else I could try? Has anyone managed to solve the problem?

UPDATE: following Apple support advice I also installed a clean version of the OS on an external disk and booted from this, but the problem persists

Comment: Not sure what the question is here. You already know that others have the same problem, your Apple dealer had the same issue so the question as written already has an answer.

Comment: This is a perfect example of *bad question, bad answer*. Technically @Yohanmaker answered your question **Is anyone else experiencing this?** but I highly doubt you wanted to know that, rather you want to solve the problem...

Answer (score -1):

I am having a similar issue with the Thunderbolt 3 Dock from Belkin, when i am using it, then it is ok, but when i send my laptop to sleep, or turn it off then the whole network collapses. i opted for disconnecting the cable from the dock every time i send the laptop to sleep or turn it off. i know it is not the best solution, but probably in the meantime you find a solution you don't have to suffer the interruption of your home network.